# Change the value of multiple h1 & h2 elements with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking to loop through and update the text within the  and  elements on the website. I have tried the below but it doesn't update the H1 tag.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("H1").innerHTML = "My New H1";

document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].innerHTML = "My New H1";
```

I also need to be able to get the number of  elements on the page and also loop through each of them and update them? How would you do this within Vanilla JS? It cannot use jQuery.

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate through the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have error in other code. This should work

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "My New H1";
```

You can also use `querySelectorAll`

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1")[0].innerHTML = "My New H1";
```

`querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByTagName` are not case-sensitive so it should work `H1` and `h1`

For looping you can use (ES5):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
if (elems.length) { 
  for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].innerHTML = 'text';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get the following error however; 

digitaliy.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at Object.run (digitaliy.js:16)
    at index.html:17

Comment: var elems = document.querySelectorAll('h1'); console.log (elems.length) - what output do you have?

Comment: Nothing, I have found the issue, i hadn't waited for the page to load, added a document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {}); and it worked

Comment: Great! I'm glad that helped you

Comment: It's not case sensitive!  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) under Notes.

Comment: Why would it be case-sensitive? HTML documents were originally meant to be written with tags in all-caps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more of one tag Hx, use `for()` to iterate through the collection.

```
var tagsh1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
for(var i=0; i<tagsh1.length; i++){
  tagsh1[i].innerHTML ='some text';
}
```

Comment: Tried this, the code runs but there is no change to the content of the h1's

Comment: Add the JS code at the end of html content, before `</body>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].innerHTML = "My New H1";
```

The above code should work on your first h1 tag node.

To loop through all the h1 elements, you could use forEach function.

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
h1.forEach((d,i)=>d.innerText = "New h1 text " + i);
```

Comment: Tried this, get the error; digitaliy.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: h1.forEach is not a function
    at Object.run (digitaliy.js:17)
    at index.html:17

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection (though on WebKit browsers it returns a  `NodeList`)... which doesn't have a `forEach` method. Create an array from it.